# how do I check if an array has the same value as the parameter?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public boolean admitHonorStudent(String firstName, String lastName,
                                          int question) {
      if(numStudent<=10){
          HS[numEmployee]=new honor(firstName,lastName, question);
          numStudent++;
          return true;
      }
      /*  for(int i = 1; i<HS.length; i++) {
          if(HS[i].getFirstname().equals(firstName) && HS[i].getLastname().equals(lastName)) {
              return false;
          }
      }*/
    return false;
}
```

The above method stores a CommissionedEmployee object to the CE array, I tried to use the for-loop to loop through the array and check if the i position of the array is the same as the parameter. So if the first and last name of the employee is the same as the one already in the array, then return false. but the for-loop doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the for-loop doesn't seem to work". What behaviour do you expect and what do you actually get?

Comment: What is the value of num_of_students? Is it possible that you are just leaving the loop early? You loop through the array of HS and immediatly leave, if either first name or last name don't match. I assume you want to check, if the given H exists in the HS array.

Answer (score 0):

Is it as simple as returning `true` if your employee check matches, ie.

```
if (CE[i].getFirstname().equals(firstName) && CE[i].getLastname().equals(lastName)) {
   return true;  // change false to true
}
```

In addition, your `for` loop index should probably start at `0`, ie.

```
for (int i=0; i<CE.length; i++) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would form an object first and then compare:

```
public boolean hireCommissionedEmployee(String firstName, String lastName,
                                          double commissionRate) {

          CommissionedEmployee object=new CommissionedEmployee(firstName,lastName, commissionRate);
          for(int i =0; i<CE.length; i++) {
             if(CE[i].equals(object) {
                return true;
          }
      }
    return false;
}
```